# Does copy command in command line is same as CopyFile in WinApi?

Tags: windows

Does the copy command in command line is same as CopyFile in Windows API?

we can copy a.txt b.txt in the cmd
And in program we can use CopyFIle(filename1, filename2, true).

Does these two same?

Comment: They do the same thing, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to know if there is any difference in the code. Does the copy command use copyFile api.

Comment: Probably, but as that's not contractual, it could change at any time.  Why do you need to know?